# Visual Studio 2017 - iOS Static Library - Remote Machine dialog

Tags: c++, ios, macos, visual-studio-2017, remote-access

I have the following projects in a solution (VS2017 Community):

- Android (Static Library)
- **iOS (Static Library)**
- Shared Code

I want to push/clean/pull the files to my mac in a comfortable way.

### OpenGLApp

When developing a OpenGLESApp1 I can get the following option in the context menu:

[image: OpenGLAppRemote Machine]

### Static Library

But when developing an static library the context menu does not show. Although files are copied when compiling, so there is a connection going on.
[image: Static Library No Remote]

So, the question is:
**How can I make that option (remote machine) appear when developing an iOS static library?** If not possible, any comfortable solution?